# How to create particular animation

Tags: swift, animation

Hi i have a question about shapes and animation of the shapes.

I would like to understand what is the best practice to create these kind of shapes (shapes that are presented on images around buttons).

Previous investigation shows that usage of the `UIBezierPath`is required but I am interest in how to create this kind of path and constantly animate it? Or probably should i use `SpriteKit` for that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Spritekit` is not necessary. You make this kind of animation just by acting on the CALayer masks. 
If you writing a series of masks based each time on a different ellipse ( and build an animations based on it), you can re-produce this effect in your button.

Some useful code examples:

```
var shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.fillColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1).CGColor
var image = UIImage(named: "some_image")
shape.contents = image?.CGImage

var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(160, 160, 240, 320))
```

[image]

Comment: It is nice answer, but is it possible to create such shape with UIBezierPathis ?

Comment: Yes, you can also add specific curve to a specific point and create particular shapes. You can find some details here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/28/ios-interpolating-points/